# Different results from LOF implementation in ELKI and RapidMiner

Tags: java, rapidminer, outliers, elki

I have written my own implementation of LOF and I'm trying to compare results with the implementations in ELKI and RapidMiner, but all 3 give different results! I'm trying to work out why.

My reference dataset is one-dimensional, 102 real values with many duplicates. I'll try and post it below.

First, the RapidMiner implementation. The LOF scores are wildly different from ELKI and from my results; many come back with a LOF of infinity. Has this implementation been validated as being correct?

My results are similar to ELKI, but I don't get exactly the same LOF values. From a quick scan of the comments in the ELKI source code, I think this may be because of differences in the way the k-neighbourhood is calculated.

In the LOF paper, the MinPts parameter (elsewhere called k) specifies the minimum no. of points to be included in the k-neighbourhood. In the ELKI implementation, I think they are defining the k-neighbourhood as exactly k points rather than all the points within the k-distance or k-distinct distance. Can anyone confirm exactly how ELKI constructs the k-neighbourhood? Also there is a private variable which allows the point itself to be included in its own neighbourhood, but it looks like the default is not to include it.

Does anyone know of a public reference dataset which has the LOF scores attached for validation purposes?

--- more details follow ---

Reference: ELKI source code is here:

http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/browser/elki/trunk/src/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/algorithm/outlier/lof/LOF.java

RapidMiner source code is here:

http://code.google.com/p/rapidminer-anomalydetection/source/browse/trunk/src/de/dfki/madm/anomalydetection/evaluator/nearest_neighbor_based/LOFEvaluator.java

Here is my test dataset:

4.32323
5.12595 5.12595 5.12595 5.12595 5.7457 5.7457 5.7457
5.7457 5.7457 5.7457 5.97766 5.97766
6.07352 6.07352 6.12015 6.12015 6.12015 6.44797 6.44797
6.48131 6.48131 6.48131 6.48131 6.48131 6.48131 6.6333
6.6333 6.6333 6.70872 6.70872 6.70872 6.70872 6.70872
6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579
6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579 6.77579
6.77579
7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654
7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654 7.03654
7.03654 7.10361 7.10361 7.10361 7.10361 7.10361 7.10361
7.10361 7.10361 7.15651 7.15651 7.15651 7.15651 7.15651
7.15651 7.15651 7.15651
8.22598 8.22598 8.22598 8.22598 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538
8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538
8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538 8.5538

For example, I get the following LOF score for the first number (4.32323):

- RapidMiner: infinity (with MinPts lower/upper bounds set to 10,100)
- ELKI: 2.6774 (with k = 10 and distfunction/reachdistfunction set to default)
- My implementation: 1.9531

Some more details on what my implementation is doing:

1. MinPts is 10, so I'm finding the 10 distinct neighbours of the point. So the neighbourhood of 4.32323 is actually 48 points, from 5.12595 up to 6.77579.
2. That gives me a k-distinct distance of 2.45256
3. I'm calculating the reachability distance of the first neighbour as 1.58277
4. I'm calculating the LRD of the sample as 1/(99.9103/48)
5. Sum of lrd(o)/lrd(p) for all 48 neighbours is 93.748939
6. Divide by 48 to get a LOF of 1.9531

Comment: Would you add the RapidMiner result for minpts=10 (without a higher max)? It would be interesting to see if it agrees, or always goes to infinity here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm actually not surprised they differ. You could also add in Weka's implementation of LOF, and you will probably get yet another answer.

Here is one more difference for you to add to your equations: as far as I know, the rapidminer implementation *merges* points that have the same coordinates. But maybe, they forgot to take these weights into account when computing the nearest neighbors!

In the classic database context, you would **not merge duplicate coordinates** into a single observation. They are still valid database records and should be counted as full records.

I do not know if any of them perform some automatic data preprocessing such as rescaling the data set.

**The ELKI implementation has been verified** against a number of textbook examples we use for teaching.

However, there are corner cases in the algorithm that are not 100% fixed, so there is room for difference even in "literal" implementations of the algorithm. You have already run into three of these:

1. How to treat duplicate points: A) aggregate, B) drop, C) consider different

   From a data mining point of view, C is correct, and A (when implemented correctly) is an optimization that can save you unnecessary distance computations. B is the common mathematical view, but does not make as much sense for a database context. If I have two "John Doe", are they the same person?
2. Definition of k nearest neighbors and k-distance.

   The usual definition of k-distance is: the smallest distance, such that at least k observations are contained. When excluding the query point, this yields the inverval up to 5.7457 from the starting point: there are 10 other observations in a radius of 5.7457 - 4.32323.

   The k nearest neighbors are usually defined as any point within this distance, which may be more than k. But then all additional objects must have the *same distance as the kth*!
   It seems as if rapidminer uses *exactly k*, which does not align with the LOF publication (see Definition 4 in the LOF publication!)

   It's really the k nearest neighbors (including ties, but other than that not more than k objects), **not the k-ths smallest *distinct* distance**. Where did you get the "distinct" from?

   Defintions 3 and 4 in the LOF publication are pretty clear on the kNN set LOF uses.

   Your neighborhood of 48 objects thus is not correct.
3. What to do if there are more than minPts duplicate points (a literal implementation will yield a division by zero, but for obvious reasons the point should be given a LOF of 1.0)

   This is maybe what is happening to Rapidminer.

And then there is reachability distance: this one is **really tricky**, because it is not a mathematical distance. It is *asymmetric*.

The reachability of the first observation *from* the second happens to be the k-distance of the second, which from a quick look (did not double check) `reach-dist(x[0], x[1]) = max(5.97766 - 5.12595, 5.12595 - 4.32323) = 0.80272`

See [my extensive tutorial slides on outlier detection](http://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Lehre/KDD/SS12/uebung/Tutorial06Outlier.pdf) for a step-by-step demonstration of how to compute LOF. As far as I can tell, this is literal LOF. It doesn't touch all the corner cases, but it motivates the design of the LOF algorithm and is quite exhaustive.

Comment: Fantastic, comprehensive answer, Erich, thanks! About the k-distinct distances, I got this from the LOF paper, after Definition 6 it says, "To deal with duplicates, we can base our notion of neighborhood on a k-distinct-distance, defined analogously to k-distance in definition 3, with the additional requirement that there be at least k objects with different spatial coordinates." This is not actually implemented in the paper, ("For simplicity, we will not handle this case explicitly but simply assume that there are no duplicates."); the 48 points is my interpretation of what the authors meant.

Comment: P.S. I also calculated the reachability distance as the k-distance of the second point, but I used the k-distinct distance which is why I got 1.58277.

Comment: OK, I made a different version of my implementation which uses k-distance instead of k-distinct distance. For the first point, I get exactly 10 neighbours, and the reachability distance of the first neighbour (5.12595) is 0.802725 as you said. The 1/LRDs are 1.174572 for the point and 0.754913, 0.41152 for the neighbours. So I work out the LOF to be 2.3349; closer to the ELKI result but still different!

Comment: 1.174572 looks good to me. But for points 2-5 I get an 1/lrd of .72518 (pay attention to those LRDs, and use the correct reachability: `lrd(o from neighbor):=max(kdist(neighbor), dist(o,neighbor))`!)

Comment: Found the problem: I was calculating the reachability distances correctly, but I was dividing the sum of reachability distances by the number of points in p's neighbourhood instead of the number of points in o's neighbourhood. Fixed it and I now get the same results as ELKI. Thank you, I'm not sure I could have figured this out without your help!

Comment: If anyone with a reputation of 2000 or more reads this thread, please can you create an "elki" tag and tag this question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Anomaly Detection Extension for RapidMiner[1] (not the build-in LOF), you will get the correct results. The build-in LOF is broken. These are the same results as ELKI. This implementation is much faster than ELKI because its multi-threated and does use much less memory, too. It also can handle duplicates (even more that k+1), where ELKI throws exceptions. (based on k-distinct)

Best,
 Hans

[1] http://marketplace.rapid-i.com/UpdateServer/faces/product_details.xhtml?productId=rmx_anomalydetection

Comment: Do you have a test case when ELKI throws an exception? When I feed it a data set with lots of duplicates, they get the - reasonable - outlier score of 1.0 for each. The ELKI LOF implementation avoids division by 0, and handles the knn as defined in the paper.